# How to get two variables from the string?

Tags: javascript

I have this string: `'foo = bar; this = is; not = necessary'`

I would like to get this result: `{"name" : "foo", "value" : "bar"}`

It is not necessary, what is after the ;

I know, I should use some regexp, but I don't really understand how regexp works.

Thanks is advance,

Comment: Will the name/value pair always appear first? Will there always be a consistent name?

Comment: Where is that string coming from? It would be more convenient if it was in the URL query-string format instead (e.g. `foo=bar&this=is&not=necessary`). Then you would parse it with corresponding functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
var values='foo = bar; this = is; not = necessary'.split('; ')[0].split(' = ');
var obj={"name" : values[0], "value" : values[1]}
```

This way you do:

1. `'foo = bar; this = is; not = necessary'.split('; ')`, which returns `['foo = bar','this = is','not = necessary']`
2. You want just the first element, so `'foo = bar; this = is; not = necessary'.split(';')[0]` gives `'foo = bar'`
3. Then you split again: `'foo = bar; this = is; not = necessary'.split(';')[0].split(' = ')`, which gives `['foo','bar']`
4. And finally you create the object

Answer (score 1):

An approach that uses regular expressions to search in a particular string, for a specified name, which will match the `foo = bar` portion of the string:

```
function getNameValuePair(string, needle) {
    if (!string || !needle) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var newNeedle = needle + '\\s+\\=\\s+\\w+',
            expr = new RegExp(newNeedle),
            parsed = string.match(expr).join(),
            parts = parsed.split(/\s+\=\s+/),
            returnObj = {'name' : parts[0], 'value' : parts[1]};

        return returnObj;
    }
}

var string = 'foo = bar; this = is; not = necessary',
    nameValueObj = getNameValuePair(string, 'foo');

console.log(nameValueObj);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eyJ5d/1/).

This could, of course, be adapted to more suit your requirements.

As it is, however:

1. The function checks that both parameters are present and, if not, simply returns `false`.
2. Creates a regular expression pattern consisting of the `needle` ('foo' in this case), followed by one, or more, units of white-space followed by a single `=` character, followed by one, or more, white-space characters. If the white-space may not always be present, it might be better to change to [`newNeedle = needle + '\\s*\\=\\s*\\w+'`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eyJ5d/2/) (the `+` matches 'one-or-more', the `*` matches 'zero-or-more').
3. creates a RegExp from that pattern,
4. tests the given string to see if it matches the pattern and, if it does, stores that match in the `parsed` variable,
5. splits the `parsed` variable with another regular expression, effectively splitting on a pattern of zero-or-more white-space followed by an `=` followed by zero-or-more white-space, storing the separated parts in the `parts` array variable,
6. constructs the object from the `parts` variable.
7. Returns that variable.

Updated the above, slightly, because two lines to create one RegExp was just *silly*:

```
function getNameValuePair(string, needle) {
    if (!string || !needle) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var expr = new RegExp(needle + '\\s+\\=\\s+\\w+'),
            parsed = string.match(expr).join(),
            parts = parsed.split(/\s+\=\s+/),
            returnObj = {'name' : parts[0], 'value' : parts[1]};

        return returnObj;
    }
}

var string = 'foo = bar; this = is; not = necessary',
    nameValueObj = getNameValuePair(string, 'foo');

console.log(nameValueObj);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/eyJ5d/3/).

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`string.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`string.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).